# Copying to an NTFS filesystem on a remote machine while presevering metadata

Tags: linux, ssh, ntfs, metadata

I want to copy a bunch of files to a NTFS partition on a remote machine while presevering the file dates. Preserving metadata on a local copy is already tricky on an NTFS filesytem:

```
$ cp -p testfile /windows/c/
cp: die Zeiten für '/windows/c/testfile' werden beibehalten: Vorgang nicht zulässig
```

(Translated: "preserving times is not admissible")

It only works when copying as root:

```
$ sudo cp -p testfile /windows/c/
```

That's already strange but I don't know a better solution, so far.

But how to copy to a remote machine? I would like to do:

```
$ scp -p testdir root@remote:/windows/c/
```

But the remote machine has only 'sudo', no password access for 'root'. I want do leave it this way. I could do:

```
$ tar testdir | ssh remote sudo tar x --directory=/windows/c
```

but I am not able to enter the 'sudo' password this way. I also tried

```
remote$ mkfifo /tmp/channel.tar
remote$ sudo tar xf /tmp/channel.tar --directory=/windows/c
$ mkdir /tmp/remote-tmp
$ sshfs remote:/tmp /tmp/remote-tmp
$ tar cf /tmp/remote-tmp/channel.tar testdir
```

but nothing happens on the remote machine. Maybe sshfs does not support FIFOs? I have no idea anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The pipe trick seems to work on the remote machine locally. SSHFS seems to be the blocker.
I found a working way without SSHFS:

```
remote$ mkfifo /tmp/channel.tar
remote$ sudo tar xf /tmp/channel.tar --directory=/windows/c
$ tar c testdir | ssh remote dd of=/tmp/channel.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tar as the container to preserve file information is a good idea.

If passwords are not an option, you could always add an ssh key to the root account on the remote machine, and do certificate based authentication.